# .htaccess root url to subfolder, and specific url to root folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My setup to weird, needless to say im particularly limited in terms of what i can change. At the moment, the easiest thing for me to change is the server's `.htaccess` file. The current directory setup looks like:

`/` is a wordpress installation

`/front-end` is a react website that uses the wordpress installations REST API to get data

I am trying to get it so that when i go to `example.com` it serves content from `/front-end` but all requests to `/dashboard` are served from the root directory.

For example these URLs would do the following:

`/` and `/contact` would point to the `index.html` file inside the `front-end` directory (react-router would pick up the `/contact`)

`/dashboard/wp-admin` and `/dashboard/wp-json/menus` would let wordpress in the route directory take over. (these would ALWAYS start `/dashboard`)

Is what im trying to achieve doable?

I have this to start with, but im unsure how to ignore the `/dashboard` route

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_URI} !-s
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/front-end/%{REQUEST_URI} -s
RewriteRule . /front-end/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?dashboard/(.*)$ /$1?wordpress=true [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^.*wordpress=true.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?front\-end.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ front-end/$1 [L,NC]
```

- In the above rules, we first check if we have `dashboard` in our requests. If yes, we deliberately attach a query string `wordpress=true` to avoid confusion with your react folder and run into a too many redirects issue.
- This way, we also know that the current request is for `wordpress` and further rewrite rules should not touch it.
- In the second rewrite rule, we check the conditions as to whether we have `wordpress=true` or not and see if this does not already have `front-end` in the URL(also applicable for internal routing and need not be explicitly specified). If it passed both tests, we redirect it to your react `front-end`, else we leave it to execute as is.
- Reason to attach `!^/?front\-end.*$` is to avoid infinite internal redirects to itself.